# htaccess Redirect 301 - Redirecting directories and subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Not sure about this one. We have a bunch of 301 Redirects.

Here are two for example:

```
Redirect 301 /about/ http://www.domain.com/about.php
Redirect 301 /about/subdirectory/ http://www.domain.com/another-page.php
```

The first one works fine, but the second one does not, since it's basically sending anything from the `/about/` directory to `/about.php` first.

So for example, when I try going to `/about/subdirectory/`, it takes me to `/about.php/about/subdirectory/` instead of just `/another-page.php`

How can I make them both go to the specific links I specify regardless of the directory setup?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove the `/about/` succeeding `/` slash like this?

```
Redirect 301 /about http://www.domain.com/about.php
```

Or you can put the condition `/about/subdirectory/` first before `/about/` depends on your need:

```
Redirect 301 /about/subdirectory/ http://www.domain.com/another-page.php
Redirect 301 /about/ http://www.domain.com/about.php
```

Remember to clear you browser cache or use a different one before checking because your browser will still cached the last permanent `301` redirection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing the order does work, I was just hoping there'd be a way to write it and it'd work regardless of the order of the links. For huge sites with tons of redirects, worrying about their order can be tedious.

Comment: @user1610904 Try to succeed the cond `/about/` with a `$` sign like `Redirect 301 /about/$ http://www.domain.com/about.php` if that will work. Or redirect its index instead its dir such `Redirect 301 /about/index.php http://www.domain.com/about.php` or `Redirect 301 /about/index.html http://www.domain.com/about.php` or else depends on the index setup of your server.